# Cannot create glossary in Cloud Translation API v3

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

I'm playing around with Cloud Translation API v3 in PHP. I went through setup process and tried simple translation shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translating-text-v3#translating_input_strings) and it worked. Then I wanted to test glossaries so I tried to add one as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#before_you_begin). When I'm trying to call the function:

```
protected function createGlossary()
    {
        $translationServiceClient = new TranslationServiceClient();
        
        $projectId = 'my-project-id';
        $glossaryId = 'my-new-glossary';
        $inputUri = 'gs://bucket/file.csv';
        
        $formattedParent = $translationServiceClient->locationName(
            $projectId,
            'us-central1'
        );
        $formattedName = $translationServiceClient->glossaryName(
            $projectId,
            'us-central1',
            $glossaryId
        );
        $languageCodesElement = 'pl';
        $languageCodesElement2 = 'en';
        $languageCodes = [$languageCodesElement, $languageCodesElement2];
        $languageCodesSet = new LanguageCodesSet();
        $languageCodesSet->setLanguageCodes($languageCodes);
        $gcsSource = (new GcsSource())
            ->setInputUri($inputUri);
        $inputConfig = (new GlossaryInputConfig())
            ->setGcsSource($gcsSource);
        $glossary = (new Glossary())
            ->setName($formattedName)
            ->setLanguageCodesSet($languageCodesSet)
            ->setInputConfig($inputConfig);

        try {
            $operationResponse = $translationServiceClient->createGlossary(
                $formattedParent,
                $glossary
            );
            $operationResponse->pollUntilComplete();
            if ($operationResponse->operationSucceeded()) {
                $response = $operationResponse->getResult();
                printf('Created Glossary.' . PHP_EOL);
                printf('Glossary name: %s' . PHP_EOL, $response->getName());
                printf('Entry count: %s' . PHP_EOL, $response->getEntryCount());
                printf(
                    'Input URI: %s' . PHP_EOL,
                    $response->getInputConfig()
                        ->getGcsSource()
                        ->getInputUri()
                );
            } else {
                $error = $operationResponse->getError();
                // handleError($error)
            }
        } finally {
            $translationServiceClient->close();
        }
    }
```

it returns an error:

```
Failed to build request, as the provided path (google.longrunning.Operations/GetOperation) was not found in the configuration.
```

It throws error at `$operationResponse->pollUntilComplete();`. The file in bucket contains just one line - `test,test`.

Then when I try to call function that lists all glossaries, it works but it doesn't return any.

What can cause this problem and how do I add glossary?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install gRPC extension for PHP.

Info: https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc

## Install gRPC for PHP

gRPC is a modern, open-source, high-performance remote procedure call framework. If you want to use PHP client libraries for gRPC-enabled APIs, you must install gRPC for PHP. This tutorial explains how to install and enable gRPC.

#### Install the gRPC extension for PHP.

```
sudo pecl install grpc
```

#### Enable the gRPC extension for PHP.

Add this line anywhere in your php.ini file, for example, /etc/php7/cli/php.ini. You can find this file by running php --ini.

```
extension=grpc.so
```

Comment: Hi, please always include some info in the answer in case the link gets broken